# VLOOKUP - Issue Finding and Returning Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having an issue with using a VLOOKUP. I have a workbook with accounts and it's information. I'm trying to match it with another list. The issue is the list utilizes the account name sometimes and then the account hierarchy others. So when I'm trying to return columns B & C, it doesn't as I believe VLOOKUP is restricted to searching the 1st column.

[image]

So basically the list I'm referencing uses either column A or D from the image above. I'm trying to get it so that it can reference A or D and return columns B and C.

Currently I have this formula, which works fine the account name is used, but not when the account hierarchy group is.

```
{=VLOOKUP(C8,Sheet5!$A$2:$D$30411,{2,3},FALSE)}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and let me know if more clarification is needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an INDEX/MATCH this way:

To get the Value from Column B:

```
=INDEX(Sheet5!B:B,IFERROR(MATCH(C8,Sheet5!A:A,0),MATCH(C8,Sheet5!D:D,0))
```

So to get C we change the B:B to C:C:

```
=INDEX(Sheet5!C:C,IFERROR(MATCH(C8,Sheet5!A:A,0),MATCH(C8,Sheet5!D:D,0))
```

Comment: so to get both columns as OP wanted, you use `=INDEX(Sheet5!B:C,IFERROR(MATCH(C8,Sheet5!A:A,0),MATCH(C8,Sheet5!D:D,0)), 0)`

Comment: I didn't even think about using two INDEX MATCH formulas! I was too busy trying to get it completed through a VLOOKUP... thanks so much for this!

Comment: @MacroMarc That will not return two values into one cell, It will return a horizontal array with two items.  To make work the OP would need to highlight two horizontal cells with the first activated put your formula in then hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter to array load into both cells.  I prefer two separate formulas over linking two cells in an array.

Comment: thanks @MacroMarc very helpful... just for reference if  anyone stumbles upon this... you need to press ctrl+alt+ent to wrap the formula in an array

Comment: @ScottCraner this is true, however, your method wouldn't return the value in one cell either, correct? Regardless, it isn't needed, but it's helpful to know how to do so! Both of your methods word when using 2 cells. Thank you both!

Comment: @M.Mill that is correct that is why I gave two formulas.  It is personal preference on linking the cells in an array, I personally do not like it as I may want to tweak one without the other, which becomes impossible when linked.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for the insight... it's much appreciated!

Comment: @ScottCraner while i have you, a quick question... how do I remove the returned zeros in either column when no match is found?

Comment: You should get an error not 0 if no match is found.  You would get 0 if a match was found and no data was in the return column.  To deal with the error; wrap the formula in `IFERROR(...,"")` where `...` is the formula.  To deal with the returned 0 you would need to `IF(...=0,"",...)` again where the `...` is the formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner, yeh I know - I was just copying the exact return type as OP's vlookup which returned an array. As he said that was working fine, I guess he's happy with that return format...

Comment: @ScottCraner yes,I already wrapped the formula in IFERROR to return a blank... I adjusted to include &"".. which looks like IFERROR(....)&"","") and that resolved the 0 returns